# Dice randomization python

Tags: python

The code I am writing is for an assignment, just looking for advice on it. The code is simple it asks the user to input how many times they want to roll two dice. The dice rolls are all random from 1-6 and those show up but I have to add the total of each individual dice roll. only problem is that my code is only saving the last dice roll and adding the last number of that list. For example if I say I want to roll the dice twice, ill get a set of 4 numbers, two for each dice when I tell the program to add them it only adds the 2nd digit of each of the rolls not all of them. So if I rolled the dice each twice, ill get 1, 2, 3, 4. The program should add the numbers like so 1+2 = 3, 3+4 = 7 and so forth depending on amount of dice rolls. All it does right now it only adds the last digit rolled on each dice so in this scenario it would only add the 2 and the 4.If anyone can help that would be great!

```
#Javier
#Dice Randomization

#Initialize
import random
numRolls = int(0)
firstDiceRoll = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
secondDiceRoll = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
totalRoll = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
dice1 = int(0)
dice2 = int(0)

#Input
numRolls = int(input("How many dice rolls?: "))

for rollCtr in range(numRolls):
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    firstDiceRoll[dice1]+=1
    print(dice1)

for rollCtr in range(numRolls):
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    secondDiceRoll[dice2]+=1
    print(dice2)

totalRoll = dice1 + dice2
print(dice1, " + ",dice2, " = ", totalRoll)


#Process


#Output
```

Current output is this:

How many dice rolls?: 2
5
5
3
4
5  +  4  =  9

Comment: Seems like you can just take the sum of `random.choices` with `k` equal to twice the number of rolls: `sum(random.choices(range(1,6), k=2*numRolls))`

Comment: One way you could do it is for each dice roll, do an elimination game of sorts to find what dice rolled. i.e. you have a 6 sided dice, so you create a list 1-6 then randomly eliminate 1 number of the list until you have only one number remaining and *that* is the dice roll. Just a thought.

Comment: What's the rationale for all these intializations? Why are `firstDiceRoll` and `secondDiceRoll` each a list of 7 zeros? What is the `totalRoll` list supposed to do? Why is `totalRoll` assigned to the sum of `dice1` and `dice2` (which are the values of the last rolls)?

Comment: ddejohn, the initializations are for another part of the assignment I am doing. The first step is to add the individual rolls and that is what I am stuck on.

Comment: You can massively simplify your program's logic: write a helper function which is called `roll_two_dice()` which takes no parameters. It should generate two numbers from `random.randint(1, 6)`, and return their sum (or a tuple of the rolls, if you want to know the individual dice rolls). Write another function called `roll_n_times(n)` which takes a parameter `n`. In it, call `roll_two_dice()` in a `for` loop `n` times, collecting the results.

Comment: Right now it looks like you're counting *dice roll frequencies*. Why are you using a `list` to do this? Have you learned about the `dict` type yet?

Comment: That is a second part of the assignment to list out the value that was rolled and the amount of times it was rolled etc. I have not learned about the dict type yet. The professor is pretty strict about not doing other things they havent taught yet lol , this is what the first part should look like                                                                    
 Output for 10 rolls


2 + 5 = 7
6 + 5 = 11
3 + 4 = 7
4 + 3 = 7
1 + 6 = 7
5 + 2 = 7
3 + 6 = 9
6 + 4 = 10
5 + 1 = 6
2 + 6 = 8

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import Set
def roll(dice: Set[int]) -> int:
    from random import choice
    while len(dice) > 1:
        dice.discard(choice(tuple(dice)))
    return dice.pop()
```

Create as many dice as you want with `range()` and `roll()` them to see their result. You can roll a 20-sided dice if you want to.

Example:

```py
# First 6 sided die
die_one = set(range(1, 7))
die_one_result = roll(die_one) # 6

# Second 6 sided die
die_two = set(range(1, 7))
die_two_result = roll(die_one) # 1
```